# What would the Jsoup selector be for TD elements that have no children and no COLSPAN attribute?

Tags: java, css-selectors, jsoup

So I'm trying to parse through a web page that is relatively messy.  It contains several key-value pairs that I would like to extract.  The unifying theme of these pairs is that they are non-empty, they have no children, and they do not have a COLSPAN attribute.  Here's what I've tried, which seems to make sense logically but does not yield any results.

```
Elements tds = document.select("td:not([colspan]):not(:has(*))");
```

So I want TDs that:

1. Do not contain COLSPAN
2. Do not have any children

Seems like I must be close, but just not having any luck.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you post a small sample of HTML?

Comment: Your selector works just for me. Which Jsoup version are you using? If the latest, then perhaps you need to post the HTML markup as well and point out what exactly you'd like to obtain so that we understand better what you really need.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with an answer that uses a loop to remove those elements that you don't want to select.

http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html

I mocked up a table that has the two situations you are trying to keep out of your select.

```
    String html = 
    "<table>" +
            "<thead><tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th></tr></thead>" +
            "<tbody>" +
                "<tr><td>row1col1</td><td>row1col2</td><td>row1col3</td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td colspan='3'>row2fullrow</td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td></td><td>row3col2</td><td><strong>row3col3</strong></td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td>row4col1</td><td colspan='2'><strong>row4col2and3</strong></td></tr>" +
            "</tbody>" +
    "</table>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    for(Element td : doc.select("td")) {
        if (td.children().size() > 0 || td.hasAttr("colspan")) {
            td.remove();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(doc);
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++
UPDATE
+++++++++++++++++++++++
I played around with it a little more and came up with this (which proves your select does work).  Your HTML must have some other little thing that I don't represent with mine.

```
    String html = 
    "<table>" +
            "<thead><tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th></tr></thead>" +
            "<tbody>" +
                "<tr><td>row1col1</td><td>row1col2</td><td>row1col3</td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td colspan='3'>row2fullrow</td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td></td><td>row3col2</td><td><strong>row3col3</strong></td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td id='x'>row4col1</td><td colspan='2'><strong>row4col2and3</strong></td></tr>" +
            "</tbody>" +
    "</table>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    System.out.println(doc.select("td:not([colspan]):not(:has(*))"));
```

Comment: You may be right.  It's anything but clean code, for sure.  I'll keep playing with it.  I did manage to get the programmatic approach to work, but still having trouble with selectors.  Will give an update once I've had time to tinker some more.